# Full disk encryption without enabiling LVM

Tags: encryption, lvm

Currently I am building an image to deploy with a fog server (used to deploy images over a network). I am using Ubuntu trusty and am required to have full disk encryption on the machines.

The issue is I can't use LVM on the image due to compatibility issues with fog but I still need full disk encryption.

It would be possible to run a script after the image is deployed to encrypt it however I am unable to find a way do do full encryption.

so my question iscan you encrypt without lvm, if not can you add full disk encryption after the main install?